# How to prove that there exist a minimum?

Tags: calculus

How do I prove that the a continuous function $f$ from $\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$f(0,0) = 0$ and

$$\lim _{||(x,y)|| → +∞} f(x,y) = 1$$

has a minimum?

Answer (score 0):

Find a closed disk $D(0,R)$ such that $\|f\|$ has values in $(\frac12, 2)$, say, outside, by the limit property. 
On the compact $D(0,R)$, the continuous $f$ will have a minimum and then argue it most be the global minimum.